# Placing legend with X coordinate as date

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a project where I'm plotting multiple plots with simulation results for different years. Project have grown and more data is needed to be displayed. Because of this I now want to have two legends, but preferebly I don't want to place them in the cornes but rather next to each other in middle. By using coordinates to place the legend this have worked for me in other projects. In this case the x-axis is a date axis and I with that I have had no success in correctly placing the legend box. I need help.

Data is formated with `as.Date`.
Data is plotted with `plot(y ~ x, ...`
I have tried

```
legend(x=as.Date("1992-04-05"),y=110, ...
legend(x=format(as.Date("1992-04-05"),"%Y-%m-%d")),y=110, ...
legend("1992-04-05",110, ...
```

and some other variants.

Thankful for help :)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, I found a solution. I didn't find a way to define date-based coordinate to place the legends in the plots, but instead I could place them with `legend("topleft",inset=c(0.3,0),...`. The `inset` function allowed me to move the legends into desired positions.